# Recursion Theorem - Incomplete proof?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

In the book "Set Theory A First Course" by Daniel Cunningham (page 90), the author presents the Recursion Theorem as follows:

**Recursion Theorem.** Let $A$ be a set and $a \in A$. Suppose that $f:A \to A$ is a function. Then there exists a unique function $h:\omega \to A$ such that

(1) $h(0)=a$

(2) $h(n^{+})=f(h(n))$, $\space$*for all* $n \in \omega$

Initially, the author defines a relation $R \subseteq \omega \times A$ as suitable if it satisfies the following two conditions:

(1) $ \left \langle 0,a \right \rangle \in R$

(2) if $ \left \langle n,u \right \rangle \in R$, then $ \left \langle n^{+},f(u) \right \rangle \in R$

Next, he defines the set $S =  \left \{ R \in \mathcal{P}(\omega \times A) : R \text{ is suitable}  \right \}$ and shows that $h = \bigcap S$ is the desired function. First, he proves $h$ is suitable, so what follows now is proving $h$ is a function by induction; this is done by defining $I = \left \{n \in\omega: \exists ! u \in A(\left \langle n,u \right \rangle \in h)\right \}$. My confusion is about the inductive step, which he tries to prove as follows:

"Let $n \in I$; that is, assume that (IH) there is a unique $u \in A$ such that $ \left \langle n,u \right \rangle \in R$. Because $h$ is suitable, we conclude that $ \left \langle n^{+},f(u) \right \rangle \in R$. To show $n^{+} \in I$, assume for the sake of contradiction that $ \left \langle n^{+},b \right \rangle \in R$ where $b \neq f(u)$. Consider the relation $R = h-\left \{ \left \langle n^{+},b \right \rangle \right \}$."

The strategy he uses here, is to prove this relation $R$ is suitable, so that $\left \langle n^{+},b \right \rangle \in R$ given that $h=\bigcap S \subseteq R$. Thus obtaining a contradiction. But my confusion is about the way he proves $R$ is suitable:

"Assume $ \left \langle n,v \right \rangle \in R$. Thus $ \left \langle n,v \right \rangle \in h$, so $ \left \langle n^{+},f(v) \right \rangle \in h$. But $u=v$ since (IH), so that $f(u)=f(v)$. Given that $f(u) \neq b$, we conclude that $ \left \langle n^{+},f(v) \right \rangle \in R$."

Why does he start assuming $ \left \langle n,v \right \rangle \in R$? Shouldn't it be proved for an ordered pair of arbitrary elements? For example, let's say I assume that $\left \langle \alpha,\beta \right \rangle \in R$. Then I would get that $\left \langle \alpha,\beta \right \rangle \in h$ and $\left \langle \alpha, \beta \right \rangle \neq\left \langle n^{+},b \right \rangle$. Thus $\left \langle \alpha^{+},f(\beta) \right \rangle \in h$ and either $\alpha \neq n^{+}$ or $\beta \neq b$. If we consider that $\alpha \neq n^{+}$, then we get that either $\alpha^{+} = n^{+}$ or $\alpha^{+} \neq n^{+}$. We observe that since the successor function is one-to-one we obtain that $\alpha=n$, but for this case it is already proved that $\left \langle \alpha^{+}, f(\beta) \right \rangle \in R$. But for the case when $\beta \neq b$, I don't see a way to prove that $R$ is suitable since there isn't more information about the function $f$. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition of suitable relation, since $(0,a) \in h$ and $(0,a) \neq (n^+,b)$, so $(0,a) \in h \setminus \{(n^+,b)\} = R$, then all we need is to show
$$(n,v) \in R \rightarrow (n^+,f(v)) \in R$$

Minor typos: some occurrences of $R$ should be replaced by $h$.

BTW, this proof is due to Lorenzen, Hilbert and Bernays.

Comment: But the proof of $R$ being suitable it's apart from the proof of $h$ being a function, so shouldn't new variables be used in order to avoid confusion?

Comment: @JuanJose:Yes, $n \in \omega$ should be an arbitrary natural number, but it is easy to save this proof. In fact, if $(m,v) \in R$ and $m \neq n$, since the successor function is one-to-one, almost the same reasoning shows $(m^+,f(v)) \in R$.

Comment: Oh, so the reason is that it's only necessary to consider the cases when $m=n$ or $m \neq n$, which means it's not necessary to know whatever happens to be the set $v$. Thanks.